# Solve is not working with this equation

Tags: equation-solving

I was trying to solve this equation and Mathematica 12 keeps trying but does not give an answer.

Is it a glitch in my system or something wrong with Mathematica 12?

```
Solve[E^((-Log[5]/2)*t)*3*Cos[330*Pi*t]==.6,t]
```

I entered this equation as part of a problem and wanted to plot a point, but it turned out that Mathematica did not respond. It is therefore something of a curiosity to see that such a complex software hangs on this.

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you provide a domain restriction you will get results:

```
Solve[E^((-Log[5]/2)*t)*3*Cos[330*Pi*t]==.6 && 0<t<.1, t]
```

> Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result.
>
> {{t -> 0.00132072}, {t -> 0.00474043}, {t -> 0.00738036}, {t -> 
>      0.010802}, {t -> 0.01344}, {t -> 0.0168636}, {t -> 0.0194996}, {t -> 
>      0.0229252}, {t -> 0.0255593}, {t -> 0.0289868}, {t -> 0.0316189}, {t -> 
>      0.0350483}, {t -> 0.0376785}, {t -> 0.0411099}, {t -> 0.0437381}, {t -> 
>      0.0471715}, {t -> 0.0497977}, {t -> 0.0532332}, {t -> 0.0558573}, {t -> 
>      0.0592948}, {t -> 0.0619169}, {t -> 0.0653564}, {t -> 0.0679765}, {t -> 
>      0.071418}, {t -> 0.0740361}, {t -> 0.0774796}, {t -> 0.0800957}, {t -> 
>      0.0835413}, {t -> 0.0861553}, {t -> 0.0896029}, {t -> 0.0922148}, {t -> 
>      0.0956646}, {t -> 0.0982744}}

Comment: Thank you, I can see why.

Comment: @Sanmuten  There appear to be 660 positive solutions and an infinite number of negative ones.